# R loop for showing top most abundant rows in multiple data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

I have 52 data files, each containing two columns: protein and abundance.
The protein column has a protein name, the abundance column contains a number showing how much of that protein there is in the sample. There are thousands of proteins in each file, and they are not in order of abundance.

Example:

sample 1

| protein | abundance |
| --- | --- |
| x | 500 |
| y | 300 |
| z | 400 |

sample 2

| protein | abundance |
| --- | --- |
| x | 300 |
| y | 800 |
| z | 200 |

I want to write a loop in R to go through all 52 files, and select the top 2 most abundant proteins from each, then make a new dataframe with 4 columns (first two containing the name of the two most abundant proteins, second two containing the abundance values for those two proteins) and 52 rows (one row for each data file).

|  | most abundant protein | second most abundant protein | abundance for MAP | abundance for SMAP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sample1 | protein x | protein z | 500 | 400 |
| sample2 | protein y | protein x | 800 | 300 |
| etc |  |  |  |  |

So far I have the following:

```
filelist<- list.files(pattern = ".csv") 

dataabund<-''

for(i in 1:length(filelist)){
  data <- read.table(filelist[i], header = T) 
  dataabund [i] <- head(arrange(data, desc(data$abundance)), n = 2)
  }

mostabund <-  data.frame(filelist, dataabund)
```

However, this creates a weird dataframe that doesn't show the abundance.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this approach -

```
library(tidyverse)

filelist<- list.files(pattern = ".csv") 

result <- map_df(filelist,~ {
  read.table(x, header = T) %>%
    slice_max(abundance, n = 2, with_ties = FALSE) %>%
    mutate(col = c('first', 'second')) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = col, values_from = c(protein, abundance))
})

result
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak! 

When I run this, I get **Error: unexpected '}' in "}"** and I can't figure out why

Comment: Yes, there was a typo. Try the updated answer @LoayJabre